# How can we select a csv file rows that contain information in a certain column in R?

Tags: r, csv, subset, selection

How can we select a csv file rows that contain information in a certain column in R?

For example, I have a csv file, which has a column called "index" but not all the rows has information on that column. I only need these rows that has information on the index. How can I select these rows and subset them in R?

[image: a csv file, only row 241 and some other rows have information on the index column. I only need these rows.]

Comment: `dat <- read.csv("path/to/file.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE); dat <- dat[dat$Index == "A1",]`

Comment: @r2evans maybe `dat$Index != ""`? I think OP wants any non-blank entries.

Comment: Hi, indeed, I need all non-blank "index". These indexes called differently. I just tried the code PN<- read.csv("PLA00101.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE) PN_Filter <- PN[!is.na(PN$Index),] but the cvs didn't change.

Comment: Did you try RyanFrost's updated answer or my comment within that answer? If you did and it still does not work, then you're likely on your own until you provide usable data. (Images of code and data are generally bad, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/.)

Answer (score 2):

Following @r2evans' approach, but assuming Index might contain values other than "A1":

```r
dat <- read.csv("path", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dat_filtered <- dat[!is.na(dat$Index) & grepl("\\S", dat$Index), ]
```

Comment: The blanks aren't NA. Maybe dat$Index != "' or !nzchar(dat$Index) would be better

Comment: If you want to guard against whitespace-only, you could replace your `dat$Index!=""` conditional with `grepl("\\S", dat$Index)` to match one (or more) non-space character. I don't know the likelihood, it's kind of hard parsing an image of data :-)

Comment: Another good suggestion! Thanks, updated. Yeah it's a bit of guesswork :D

Answer (score 0):

In an easily readable but somewhat not fancy way:

```
index <- table$Index
selector <- nchar(index)>0 & !is.na(index)
table[selector]
```

If you're using data.table:

```
DT[!is.na(Index) & nchar(Index)>0, ]
```